# Salesforce equivalent of setFormNotification() in Dynamics for conditional record page alerts?

Tags: notification, alert

My employer is beginning the process of switching over to a Salesforce org from our current Dynamics CRM 2015 on-prem solution.  We have a situation in Dynamics where we would like to use setFormNotification()
(a JavaScript function provided by Dynamics) to conditionally display a warning notification at the top of the page on certain Contact records, and I have been asked if this same type of function is available in Salesforce.

Does anyone know if Lightning Experience includes a similarly simple way to conditionally add custom persistent notifications at the top of a record page based on data in the record?  Here is an example image from Dynamics:

[image: example image of Dynamics persistent form notifications]

Comment: I guess you can create a single component which takes a message and severity as design attribute and control its visibility based on conditions like field values, form factor, the user profile etc. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&language=en_us&type=5

Comment: @manjit5190 Thanks for the quick comment!  I've been working through trailhead content, but haven't learned much about Lightning Pages yet – can a custom component be added to a default lightning record page, or would I have to completely replace the object's default record page with a new custom lightning page in order to add a custom component?

Comment: Yes, technically you are editing the default page which creates a new page that can be assigned as org default. See https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_recordpage and

Comment: I second this. Bonus: once you've created the component, you can use it on any page and have its conditions based on a point-and-click configuration, so you don't have to write code over and over again.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Seems like a pretty viable solution.  Thanks, @manjit5190, this was very helpful!

Comment: @sfdcfox, that sounds fantastic - looking forward to learning more about custom lightning pages and components!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding comments as an answer:

You can create a single component which takes a message and severity as design attribute and control its visibility based on conditions like field values, form factor, the user profile etc. [See here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5)

Technically you are editing the default page which creates a new page that can be assigned as org default. See how you can do it [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_recordpage).